# Moderation indicator's behavior: Clarification needed

Tags: bug, moderation

I have an active icon on the top of SE, stating that I have 18 total posts awaiting review. I still have that message active even after I went ahead and reviewed all available to me categories: Close Votes, First Posts, Late Answers, Low Quality Posts, Reopen Votes, Suggested Edits. Why does the counter still indicate that I have posts awaiting review, while it is clearly not the case? Am I missing something?

P.S. I have added `bug` tag, which I will remove upon confirmation that that behavior is expected.

Comment: See [Review counts in top-bar and /review don't match](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233535/254929) on MSE.

Comment: @Air: Thank you for the link.

Comment: No problem. [Caching is also often involved](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) so the counter may not be consistently "off" from one moment to the next.

Comment: @Air: Hmm... I've just read the thread. Still don't understand why it's designed that way (discounting caching). Too confusing.